# New Cordova InAppBrowser buttons

Tags: cordova

Is there a way to style or, at least, set the desired buttons in a new browser window?

I know I can do it with ChildBrowser plugin, and that it can live with the new Cordova - but we want to try the new InAppBrowser as a standard.

Thanks

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Good point. We are using it for iOS now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've playing a bit with it and I could add a new button by duplicating the Close button code inside the **CDVInAppBrowser.m** file. Then I changed the name closeButton by shareButton and the function callback by one new function wnShare like this:

```
self.shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(wnShare)];
self.shareButton.enabled = YES;
self.shareButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.shareButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
self.shareButton.width = 38.000;
```

Then you can add action you want to perform when the button is clicked by adding code to the new function:

```
- (void)wnShare
{
    /* Whatever ou want to do when the button is tapped goes here */
}
```

Right now I'm looking on how to open a dialogbox and show many share links to share the current website displayed through different social medias.
If you have some clue please tell :-)

I wrote a full list of modification into my blog if anyone needs that:
http://blog.cubeinspire.com/how-to-add-a-new-event-type-into-cordova-2-4-0-phonegap-2-4-0-to-the-plugin-inappbrowser/